# asp.net + listbox +change of value

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have a listbox in asp.net

```
 <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" class="listItem" runat="server" 
 onselectedindexchanged="ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged">
 <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
 </asp:ListBox>
```

I want to trigger a function when somebody changes it values...
code which i tried is

```
protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label6.Text = Label6.Text + "hello";
}
```

What's wrong here..

By setting the autopostback as true, my problem is solved but the page is reloaded everytime i change its value which i dnt want as large amount of data get reloaded on every autopostback(bcoz of images on the page).Even i put the following code in page load

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
        }
    }
```

but it didnt work out...

Comment: nothing seem to be wrong, what are you expecting

Comment: value of label6 is not changing

Comment: Add the `autoPostBack="true"` to your `asp:ListBox` - only when it postsback will you fire that code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you expect that the `SelectedIndexChanged` event is triggered immediately. But by default the `ListControl`'s [`AutoPostBack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.autopostback.aspx) property is set to `false`.

> `true` if a postback to the server automatically occurs whenever the
>   user changes the selection of the list; otherwise, `false`. **The default
>   is false**.

So set it to true:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" AutoPostBack="true" class="listItem" runat="server" 
 onselectedindexchanged="ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged">
 <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
 </asp:ListBox>
```

Comment: @arrestwarrant: You have to decide if you want to postback always or you want to postback only if the user clicks a "save-button" or so. Btw, the `!Page.IsPostBack` in your code is empty, are you databinding the controls there? Another option would be to use ASP.NET Ajax to render only the related part of the page and not all.

Comment: i dnt want to use save button...the application restricts me to add more button. :(

Answer (score 1):

`AutoPostBack="true"` is missing add it on `ListBox1`